# ggplot2: Logistic Regression points on the regression line, instead on the 0 and 1

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, statistics, logistic-regression

I'm trying to generate a logistic regression plot with the points on the regression line as in this example:

[image]

What I get is the following:

[image]

I searched all over the internet but couldn't find anything helpful, and I've tried different combinations on ggplot myself, but nothing good came out.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
g <- ggplot(myData, aes(speed, GetResp.RESP))
g + geom_point(aes(color = PadLen, shape = PadLen), size = 2.5) +
  geom_smooth(method = "glm", method.args = list(family = "quasibinomial"), aes(color = PadLen), se = FALSE, size = 1.1) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "red"), labels = c("SmallPaddle", "BigPaddle")) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(1, 2), labels = c("SmallPaddle", "BigPaddle")) +
  theme_classic() + theme(legend.title = element_blank(), legend.position = c(0.8, 0.20)) +
  xlab("Ball Speed (cm/s)") +
  ylab('Proportion of "Fast" Responses') +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(.0, .2, .4, .6, .8, 1.0), labels = c(".0", ".2", ".4", ".6", ".8", "1.0"))
```

Here is a reduced sample of the database, enough to get something to work with:

(If the dput code doesn't work, you can download the dput.R from here, and use dget(): https://file.io/PsBLeJ)

```
structure(list(Subject = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), GetResp.RESP = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), PadLen = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), speed = c(36.7686063997867, 26.5851542237119, 31.4488143078996, 26.5851542237119, 48.1629567594045, 36.7686063997867, 42.3730800240861, 22.4757186261048, 31.4488143078996, 31.4488143078996, 48.1629567594045, 48.1629567594045, 26.5851542237119, 42.3730800240861, 36.7686063997867, 48.1629567594045, 22.4757186261048, 36.7686063997867, 22.4757186261048, 42.3730800240861, 22.4757186261048, 22.4757186261048, 48.1629567594045, 31.4488143078996, 31.4488143078996, 31.4488143078996, 48.1629567594045, 26.5851542237119, 48.1629567594045, 36.7686063997867, 42.3730800240861, 26.5851542237119, 22.4757186261048, 42.3730800240861, 26.5851542237119, 42.3730800240861, 36.7686063997867, 42.3730800240861, 31.4488143078996, 36.7686063997867, 22.4757186261048, 22.4757186261048, 42.3730800240861, 31.4488143078996, 22.4757186261048, 31.4488143078996, 36.7686063997867, 48.1629567594045, 31.4488143078996, 26.5851542237119, 22.4757186261048, 26.5851542237119, 36.7686063997867, 36.7686063997867, 48.1629567594045, 36.7686063997867, 26.5851542237119, 42.3730800240861, 31.4488143078996, 42.3730800240861, 26.5851542237119, 42.3730800240861, 42.3730800240861, 48.1629567594045, 31.4488143078996, 36.7686063997867, 31.4488143078996, 48.1629567594045, 26.5851542237119, 36.7686063997867, 22.4757186261048, 48.1629567594045, 22.4757186261048, 42.3730800240861, 26.5851542237119, 42.3730800240861, 26.5851542237119, 48.1629567594045, 42.3730800240861, 31.4488143078996, 26.5851542237119, 36.7686063997867, 22.4757186261048), backCol = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), sample = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L), backColor = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("blue", "red"), class = "factor"), WasHit = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), RedBlue.Cycle = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), RedBlue.Sample = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -83L))
```

Comment: I'm confused by what you're trying to change. The variable you've plotted on your y-axis only has 0s and 1s, so that's all that shows up on the plot. Do you instead want to plot *probabilities* that each observation is  a 1 or 0? That's data that isn't actually in this sample

Comment: Hi, yes I wanted to plot the probabilities. It used to work before with the code I provided, but after an update to ggplot2 it changed to 0's and 1's. I thought they changed some function or parameter, but it seems like not.

Comment: Are you positive that this same code worked with this same data before? Because what you've plotted is 1s and 0s, so I don't know how any other data would show up

Comment: Yes, very positive. It probably was a feature that generated the plot from the fitted model instead of the data itself, and then they changed it. Not sure about this, but 100% about the code, as I got it from an archive with the project that I used to work at some time, and it did work back then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made the plots below because it is a bit too long to comment. So I am not very sure what exactly are the plots on the regression line you showed in the first plot. If they are points from your regression line, they should fall exactly on the line. I think they might be generated from another fit that is not the same as the line. Anyhow, to show the predicted values for each unique data point:

```
# basic plot with points
g <- ggplot(myData, aes(speed, GetResp.RESP,color = PadLen,shape = PadLen)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "glm", method.args = list(family = "quasibinomial") , se = FALSE, size = 1.1) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "red"), labels = c("SmallPaddle", "BigPaddle")) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(1, 2), labels = c("SmallPaddle", "BigPaddle")) +
  theme_classic() + 
  xlab("Ball Speed (cm/s)") +
  ylab('Proportion of "Fast" Responses') 

#with data points
g1 = g+geom_point(size = 2.5)

# with predicted values from data points
fit = glm(GetResp.RESP~speed*PadLen,family=quasibinomial,data=myData)
datapts = sort(unique(myData$speed))
plotdf = data.frame(speed=rep(datapts,2),
PadLen=factor(rep(0:1,each=length(datapts))))
plotdf$GetResp.RESP = predict(fit,plotdf,type="response")

g2 = g + geom_point(data=plotdf)
```

[image]

Comment: I think they set the points to be generated from data, instead of the model, which is kind of weird, since the lines are based on the model. Also, your code worked as I wanted, so thank you!